# Using id attribute gotten from click on another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the id of a button that I got from clicking on it but it's not working

```
var idClicked;

$("input").click(function(e){
    var idClicked = $(this).attr('id');
});

$(idClicked).on('click',function(e){
    ...
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `idClicked` ?

Comment: Try adding a hash in front '#'+idClicked

Comment: If you got the id of the control properly, then add # before the id $("#"+idClicked).on('click',function(e){
    ...
});

Comment: But why .......?

Comment: Even ignoring the problem with the variable declaration, the `$(idClicked).on('click',...)` part would run immediately when the page loads, *before* the user has clicked. One way to solve that is to do that inside the first click handler (and - depending on your requirement - unbind any previous click handler associated with a previously clicked item).

Answer (score 0):

When you place `var` keyword before a variable name, JS will attempt to create that variable in the local scope. So, declaring a variable with the same name inside and outside a function would block the function from accessing the variable outside.

the `idClicked` variable that you have declared outside the function, therefore,  is not updated from within the function.

The correct construct should be:

```
var idClicked;

$("input").click(function(e){
    idClicked = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Also, the variable `idClicked` is only assigned a value when you clickm on the `input`. So, using `idClicked` should be done only after the first click is done.

Probably you can bring the second event code inside the first one. This should solve your variable scope problem too.

```
$("input").click(function(e){

    var idClicked = $(this).attr('id');


  $('#' + idClicked).on('click',function(e){
    ...
  });

});
```

Comment: Variable scope was *one* problem, but then the next part of the code (not shown in your answer) will still be `$(undefined).on('click'...)` because it runs before the value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this keyword you can also use target to get the id.

```
    var idClicked;
    $("input").click(function(e){
        idClicked = e.target.id;
    });
    if(idClicked!=undefined ){
    $("#"+idClicked).on('click',function(e){
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Variable scope was *one* problem, but now instead of `$(undefined).on('click'...)` this'll give `$("#undefined").on('click'...)` - either way `idClicked` is used before the user clicks.

Comment: can you tell what is input in the code $("input").click(function(e){ ?

Comment: If you get undefined, then you are not getting that element in code, input a class name? or div name? or what?

Comment: My point is the `$("#" + ...` part runs immediately, *before* the user clicks on anything, so at that point `idClicked` has the value `undefined`.

Comment: If it is in page load, then add a condition before for value check. updated code

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because you declare event and declare in the same element by id another event again, and every click will cause double event handler that running... that all they is to declare again and again the event but never will execute your logic code.

Another important thing is that you can't have 2 elements with same id attribute.

what you need to do is to put 2 elements with different id's

```
<input type="text" id="myid">
<button id="button_myid">my button</button>
```

and your javascript code like that

```
$("input").click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var buttonId = "button_" + id;
        $("#"+buttonId).trigger("click");
    });

    $("#button_myid").click(function(e) {
        // do stuff
    });
```

this structure will let you the ability to trigger click event on another elements.

the base with this code is that you catch click event on the input, and trigger the event on the button that his ID name contain the id of the input (with prefix "**button_**").

But pay attention that on every button you need to declare the relevant event.